# Update ruby version on MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm trying to update ma ruby version.
I'm with ruby 1.8.7 and I would like to install 2.1.0.
I just installed `rvm`, `rbenv`, `brew` and gem.

But when I try to do

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.0.
```

I get an error about clang. I don't get the point between clang and ruby

Could you please help me?

Error:

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.0
Downloading ruby-2.1.0.tar.gz...
Installing ruby-2.1.0...

BUILD FAILED
...
Last 10 log lines:
...
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking for gcc-4.2... no
checking for clang... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
./configure: line 3390: -E: command not found
configure: error: clang version 3.0 or later is required
```

Comment: Ruby's core libraries (string, integer, etc) are built in C, hence CLANG. What OS version of OSX are you on? It is complaining about an old CLANG version. Have you tried installing via `rvm` instead?

Comment: i tried with rvm. i get an error about my Xcode version. It works after i update my xcode version. Thank you. Is there any link between xcode et ruby?

Comment: If you prefer rbenv,  Sstephenson suggests to fully uninstall RVM, see [the installation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to install the Developer Tools command-line tools in order to build Ruby. As one option, you can install Xcode from the App Store, and Xcode will let you install the command line tools if they aren't automatically installed with your version.

Comment: `brew doctor` should tell you how to do this.

Comment: I have the same issue and followed the advice. Still I get the error:

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Brew doctor does not provide help, xcode-select --install says: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: I have the same issue. Everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You can install developer command line tools without installing Xcode. Just type the following in the terminal:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```